# MongoDB tunable Consistency Best practices

Tags: java, mongodb

I come from distributed cassandra NoSQL background..Currently I'm working on MongoDB project..Are there any common practices like Cassandra's Read/Write Consistency `QUORUM` in MongoDB replica sets to achieve Strong Consistency? I have gone through MongoDB's Documentation for different read/write concerns that we can apply as per application needs..But i was wondering if there any best practices that people adopt in production grade MongoDB?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest analog of Cassandra's `QUORUM` is the [Majority Write Concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) option, which will wait for a majority of your replica set's voting members to acknowledge a write before the operation completes successfully. You can also specify how many members you wish to acknowledge the write manually, and can request up to all available members.

In production (or any use case for that matter), `Majority` write concern can wait for quite a long time to complete if your secondaries are in a different geographic region, under strain, or manually delayed using the `slaveDelay` option in your Replica Set config.
Use the `majority` write concern option only for data that you need to *absolutely guarantee* is replicated across your replica set. Most of the time a write concern of `2` is sufficient for this.

Comment: thanks..agreed that there shouldn't be any issue with `Majority` write concern as long as replicas are within same Data center..My application have requirement to save incoming transactions in mongodb so that it can be replayed later..what would be the best Read Write approach..Note my reads are not too often but writes are..

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. "To save incoming transactions...so that [they] can be replayed later" sounds like what MongoDB already does. Using write concern just ensures that your writes make it to a minimum number of  secondaries.

Comment: i mean my app is going to persist every incoming transaction into mongodb...lots of writes and less regular reads...So I'm thinking of how my cluster would look like with different write concerns in place